# Fastest mail server for full body searching

Tags: email, imap, zimbra, cyrus

I'm looking for the fastest mail server software currently available. I'm looking to store around 900GB of mail. I need to be able to perform full body searches across all messages via IMAP and get a response within a reasonable time. Currently I am using Cyrus and I seem to be getting at its very limit even with enabling the squatter index.

I have looked at Zimbra and it ticks every box part from the fact it does not support per user flags across public folders.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a mail journaling solution? Searching across that large a dataset seems like it would be difficult with what you're proposing.

My preferred method is to use **[MailArchiva](https://www.mailarchiva.com/enterprisefeatures?page=freeedition)** in its free or commercial version. It works with Exchange, Sendmail, Zimbra, etc. and is powered by the [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) search engine.

This would leave you free to use the mail solution of your choice and not have to impose such a hefty search requirement.